# Pandas group by cumsum keep columns

Tags: pandas, group-by, cumsum

I have spent a few hours now trying to do a "cumulative group by sum" on a pandas dataframe. I have looked at all the stackoverflow answers and surprisingly none of them can solve my (very elementary) problem:

I have a dataframe:

`df1
Out[8]: 
   Name        Date  Amount
0  Jack  2016-01-31      10
1  Jack  2016-02-29       5
2  Jack  2016-02-29       8
3  Jill  2016-01-31      10
4  Jill  2016-02-29       5`

I am trying to

1. group by ['Name','Date'] and
2. cumsum 'Amount'.
3. That is it.

So the desired output is:

`df1
Out[10]: 
   Name        Date  Cumsum
0  Jack  2016-01-31      10
1  Jack  2016-02-29      23
2  Jill  2016-01-31      10
3  Jill  2016-02-29      15`

EDIT: I am simplifying the question. With the current answers I still can't get the correct "running" cumsum. Look closely, I want to see the cumulative sum "10, 23, 10, 15". In words, I want to see, at every consecutive date, the total cumulative sum for a person. NB: If there are two entries on one date for the same person, I want to sum those and then add them to the running cumsum and only then print the sum.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need assign output to new column and then remove `Amount` column by [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
df1['Cumsum'] = df1.groupby(by=['Name','Date'])['Amount'].cumsum()
df1 = df1.drop('Amount', axis=1)
print (df1)
   Name        Date  Cumsum
0  Jack  2016-01-31      10
1  Jack  2016-02-29       5
2  Jack  2016-02-29      13
3  Jill  2016-01-31      10
4  Jill  2016-02-29       5
```

Another solution with [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
df1 = df1.assign(Cumsum=df1.groupby(by=['Name','Date'])['Amount'].cumsum())
         .drop('Amount', axis=1)
print (df1)
   Name        Date  Cumsum
0  Jack  2016-01-31      10
1  Jack  2016-02-29       5
2  Jack  2016-02-29      13
3  Jill  2016-01-31      10
4  Jill  2016-02-29       5
```

EDIT by comment:

First `groupby` columns `Name` and `Date` and aggregate `sum`, then `groupby` by `level` `Name` and aggregate `cumsum`.

```
df = df1.groupby(by=['Name','Date'])['Amount'].sum()
        .groupby(level='Name').cumsum().reset_index(name='Cumsum')
print (df)
   Name        Date  Cumsum
0  Jack  2016-01-31      10
1  Jack  2016-02-29      23
2  Jill  2016-01-31      10
3  Jill  2016-02-29      15
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, however the second group should lump together Jack's multiple 2016-02-29 Amounts. So the Cumsum must only have four rows reading "10, 23, 10, 15". I will try to work with what you have provided nevertheless, thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Set the index first, then groupby.

```
df.set_index(['Name', 'Date']).groupby(level=[0, 1]).Amount.cumsum().reset_index()
```

[image]

---

After the OP changed their question, this is now the correct answer.

```
df1.groupby(
    ['Name','Date']
)Amount.sum().groupby(
    level='Name'
).cumsum()
```

This is the same answer provided by jezrael

Comment: Thanks for the response. As per my edit, your solution does not give the desired output, however I believe you have provided good direction. Thank you

Comment: Whoever gave me a down vote, please reconsider as the OP changed their question after the answer was given.  I didn't want to appear to copy jezrael's answer so I just referred to it.

Comment: Hi piRSquared, I downvoted because the original desired output (even before the EDIT) was not achieved with your code - so at least not an upvote imho. However in hindsight you did provide `set_index` which solved my secondary problem so I will upvote. Thanks again

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response and the help

Comment: Just a note: This solved an issue for me with cumsum() not including the groupby column.  So thanks!