# Cumulative Sum in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
project_code   start_date   end_date   date       spend
     489        5/15/18     5/15/19     3/1/19     100
     489        5/15/18     5/15/19     4/1/19     250
     489        5/15/18     5/15/19     5/1/19     50
     511        4/1/19      4/1/20      2/1/20     90
     511        4/1/19      4/1/20      3/1/20     50       
     489        5/15/19     5/15/20     3/1/20     100
```

I need to create another column in the same table which calculates the cumulative spend for that subscription period (defined by start and end date). So it should add all previous spends under a project code so long as they have the same start/end date.

```
project_code   start_date   end_date   date       spend    cumulative_subscription_spend
     489        5/15/18     5/15/19     3/1/19     100           100
     489        5/15/18     5/15/19     4/1/19     250           350
     489        5/15/18     5/15/19     5/1/19     50            400
     511        4/1/19      4/1/20      2/1/20     90            90
     511        4/1/19      4/1/20      3/1/20     50            140
     489        6/1/19      6/1/20      3/1/20     100           100
```

Most versions I have seen of this problem use groupby/aggregate but I am having trouble figuring out how that would work as a new column in the same table.

Comment: Try `pandas.DataFrame.cumsum`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas group by cumsum keep columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41808951/pandas-group-by-cumsum-keep-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with `groupby` + `cumsum`

```
df['cumulative_subscription_spend'] = df.groupby('project_code')['spend'].cumsum()
```

Comment: This worked when I grouped by both 'project_code' and 'start_date'